# Sinch app to phone call pricing from user network provider directly

Tags: android, phone-call, sinch

I'm developing a messaging application  using sinch SDK and I want to use their app to phone calling option but it needs me to put some money in my account at sinch for pricing but instead I want to take the price of the call directly from the user through his phone network provider just like all the applications that use app to phone calls but I don't know how to do it,can anybody help me or tell me how to do it ?

Comment: Just for the person who sees that this question is unclear or not useful, can you declare why?, or that you just read it and found that you don't understand it so you decided to mark it as not clear and not useful?

Answer (score 1):

Sinch doesn't offer the possibility to directly charge the end user. Instead, it lets you manage end users payments in whatever way suits you best - while it bills the app developer directly for all calls.

Comment: What I was asking is if there a way to get the price of the call from the network provider of the user and get it into my sinch account, like an sdk or librarry to do the pricing, and thanks for your efforts.